# Why my document sometimes does not want to be opened?

Tags: pdf, miktex, compiling

I am almost a complete beginner in this area of document-writing, so I have a few questions.

In a period of less than a day I downloaded MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXstudio and wrote a document with some mathematical formulae but also I am facing some problems.

I do it like this:

1) I am writing a text file in Notepad

2) Then I save the file as .txt file with given name ch.tex

3) Then I open that file in either TeXstudio or MiKTeX and, if in MiKTeX then I press the green button that has "Typeset" function and when I press that button after a few moments a new window appears in which I see how my document will look in .pdf format when opened in Adobe Acrobat Reader, and if in TeXstudio  I press also green button that has "Compile" function

4) After that, I save my file in .pdf format

But, after all of that, sometimes my document does not want to be opened in Adobe Acrobat Reader

Am I doing something completely wrong?

Is there any faster and safer and better way to write a document than this way of mine?

Why sometimes documents, after being written and saved as .txt file, and then opened and "Typesetted" or "Compiled" and then saved as a .pdf file, do not want to be opened in Adobe Acrobat Reader but they want to be opened (after pressing the "Typeset button") in MiKTeX window where it is shown how they will look like in Adobe Acrobat Reader?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You mention you've installed TeXstudio (as well as MikTeX). If so, why do you edit files in Notepad instead of directly in TeXstudio? (If nothing else, by skipping this step, you'll save yourself the hassle of having to override the default file name extension `.txt` and having to choose `.tex` instead.) By the way, have you checked that the full file name is maybe `ch.tex.txt`? If so, that would easily explain why the file isn't being compiled...

Comment: @Mico It is being compiled, but it is not always being able to be opened in AAR.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin Just to clarify, after compiling your .tex file, the ouput .pdf file cannot be opened in AAR?If and when the pdf file does not open, is there any error message and what is it?

Comment: Please be more specific as to the context of the claim that "sometimes my [pdf] document does not want to be opened". Do the times the tex file doesn't compile correctly maybe correspond to the times the pdf file cannot be opened successfully in Acrobat Reader?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin: If you want something faster or less click-to-compile-y, then consider using an online environment where you don't have to compile; they compile for you as soon as you've completed your changes. [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) springs to mind.

Comment: @Troy Yes there is an error message but I do not remember what is said in it, if I manage to reproduce it again I will tell you. But isnt the set of all possible error messages "small""? That is, can you generally know what is happening?

Comment: @Troy I think it is this one:

Error: the document is damaged and cannot be repaired. Adobe Reader could not open because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

Comment: texstudio is an editor for writing tex files, you should use that, since you installed it, not notepad, but that is not the cause of your error.

Comment: if you get the error from acrobat that the pdf is corrupt it probably means that tex dis not finish so the pdf is complete. so the important information is what error did you get from tex and what tex input did you make that made an error, if you gave that information someone could tell you how to fix your document.

Comment: You shouldn't do step 4. The compilation already creates a pdf. It is in your document folder. Don't overwrite it by saving another file on top of it. (Step 1 and 2 are unnecessary. You can write your files directly in texstudio or texworks.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, I figured by experiment that step 4) causes problems, but of course, as an almost a complete amateur I do not understand why. Your comment is helpful.